# Can we able to send sms without using smscomposertask class in windows phone 8 application?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have searched for that but i am unable to find it please let me know the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already search this information with microsoft MVP in "Windows Phone trainning meeting" (sorry for my english) and In Windows Phone 7.1 and + It's not possible.

You can use [SmsComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but you know that...

You can also go through the API to send SMS, but it's not Native... exemple : [clockworksms](http://www.clockworksms.com/) ...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No
Long answer: There is no other API for sending SMS messages right now than SmsComposeTask in Windows Phone 7 or 8.